# Introduce topology on ${\mathbb{R}}$: $A = U\setminus C$ is open ($U$ is open in standard topology and $C$ is no more than countable. Is it regular?

Tags: general-topology

Introduce topology on ${\mathbb{R}}$: $A$ is open only if $A = U\setminus C$ (where $U$ is open in standard topology and $C$ is no more than countable)

Why this space is not regular?

$\
$

IMHO:

${\mathbb{R}}\setminus {\mathbb{Q}}$ is open, ${\mathbb{Q}}$ is closed. So let's take $\forall$ open set $O$, which contains ${\mathbb{Q}}$. $\forall x \in {\mathbb{Q}}$ is in $O$ with some neighbourhood. Also, ${\mathbb{Q}}$ is everywhere dense in ${\mathbb{R}}$ with the standard topology, so $\forall$ neighbourhood of $\forall$ point intersects with $O$ by some neighbourhood of $y \in {\mathbb{Q}}$. The neighbourhood has a power of the continuum, therefore if we throw away a not more than countable amount of points, there still will be some of them left. So $T_3$ doesn't work.

But as I was said, it is not the right proof. How to prove it elsehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some correct ideas but you have to be more precise:

$\Bbb Q$ is indeed closed in this new topology and $\pi \notin \Bbb Q$ (we could have picked any irratonal point, but I like $\pi$).

Suppose now that we have $U$ and $V$ open, so of the form $U_0 \setminus C_0$ resp. $V_0 \setminus C_1$, with $U_0,V_0$ Euclidean open and $C_0,C_1$ at most countable (possibly empty), and such that

$$\pi \in U, \Bbb Q \subseteq V, U \cap V=\emptyset$$

Clearly $V_0$ is dense and open in the Euclidean topology (it contains $\Bbb Q$) and so $U_0$ intersects $V_0$ and $U_0 \cap V_0$ is thus Euclidean open hence uncountable (all such sets contain open intervals). So note that

$$ U \cap V =(U_0 \setminus C_0) \cap (U_1 \setminus C_1) \supseteq (U_0 \cap V_0) \setminus (C_0 \cup C_1)$$

and $U \cap V$ cannot be empty, as $C_0 \cup C_1$ is at most countable and the right hand set is uncountable. This contradiction shows $X$ is not regular.

Answer (score 0):

If space is regular, then as Q is closed and $\pi$ not in Q,
exists open disjoint U,V with $\pi$ in U and Q subset V.
Thus exists a,b,u,v and countable K,L with
$\pi$ in (a,b) - K subset U and $\pi$ in (u,v) subset V $\cup$ L.
Pick r,s with $\pi$ in (r,s) subset (a,b) $\cap$ (u,v).
Whereforth, (r,s) - K subset U and (r,s) - L subset V.
As K and L are countable,
((r,s) - K) $\cap$ ((r,s) - L) is uncountable.
Whence U $\cap$ V is uncountable,
contradicting the assumption of regularity.